# Rails Associations: belongs_to has_many confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've read through the following [tutorial](http://mayurrokade.com/blog/rails-associations-beginner-pitfalls/) and found the curious line:

*notice that the create function is written in such a way that there has be a `@post` before creating a `@comment`.*

You can see the supporting controller code:

```
Class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  ----
  def create
    @post = Post.find(current_post)
    @comment = @post.comments.create(post_params)  ## 'Essential stuff'
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to action: :index, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end 
    end
  end
  ----
end
```

Indeed, "`current_post`" implies that the post was created BEFORE the comment.

But what if I want both to be created simultaneously? For example, suppose my USER `has_many` EMAILS, and each EMAIL `belongs_to` a USER. Then, when creating a new user, I may want to have an expandable form that allows the user to add one, two, three, or twenty emails while creating his account.

How could this be done?

Comment: Also have look at this - http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1.

Answer (score 1):

Nested Attributes is the rails way of doing what you want to achieve.

Checkout http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider using nested form, have a look into this [gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), very easy to implement. It will allow the user to add multiple emails as required.

Comment: That gem looks nice, but I find it not very easy to implement considering their tutorial is written in HAML....and not erb.

Comment: @ineedahero its pretty simple, where you have  = f.inputs do you can do  <%= f.inputs do %>